# Custom domain for NodeJS deployment on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I have deployed Node JS on Google App Engine successfully however after deployment it provides me url like `https://mydomain-473829.uc.r.appspot.com` how can I custom to use my own subdomain like `https://api.mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) to map the domain/subdomain to your app.

Note that after you set up your custom domain and update the DNS records, a managed SSL certificate is automatically provided within a few minutes by Google. If you don't want to use Google managed SSL certificates, you may also take a look at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#using_your_own_ssl_certificates)  on how to setup your own SSL certificates.